# Не могу отправить данные через mail() php на mail.ru

Tags: php

Здраствуйте. Не могу отправить данные через mail() php на mail.ru. На другие почты приходят, но не на mail.ru. Подскажите пожалуйтв

```
`<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {
    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {
    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);
    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}
$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";
function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;
mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю у mail с недавних пор ужесточились правила отправки писем для борьбы со спамом и использовать mail() для отправки запрещено, да и со временем дешёвые хостинги Вам сами заблочат отправку этим методом. Возможно даже smtp у mail.ru запрещён для отправки писем со сторонних сайтов. Остаётся использовать только smtp от yandex и gmail.